# Building CMake Project for WSL 2 Linux Distro Fails

Tags: c++, cmake, wsl-2, visual-studio-2022

I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview because I wanted to be able to debug/run for my WSL 2 Ubuntu distro from my Windows machine. Unfortunately, when I start the build, I keep getting the following error: `Failed to get permissions for file '{0}'`. Has anyone run into this issue and fixed it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a Linux permissions problem.

Comment: Same thing happens to me when I switch to one of my two WSL 2 distros.  My Ubuntu 22 distro works fine, but as soon as I switch the Target System drop-down to CentOS 7, `Failed to get permissions for file [some_GUID]`.